# How to execute bash function inside other function

Tags: bash, cygwin

I have this code:

```
myecho() {
    if [ -z "$1" ]
        then
            echo "if";
    else
        echo "else";
    fi
}
alias myecho=myecho

callmyecho() {

        append="stuff";
        myechoResult='myecho'; #`myecho` wont execute here!
        echo $myechoResult$append 
}
```

How I can execute `myecho` inside `callmyecho` and append a new text to it?

Comment: just write `myecho` . Also that alias is pointless. Also you never call the `callmyecho` function.

Comment: I will call callmyecho from bash I am learning how to call functions

Comment: Remove `alias` command and instead of `myechoResult='myecho'` use `myechoResult=$(myecho)`

Comment: Once you learn to love functions, you won't have a need for aliases (except for the most simple ones)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing your code as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

myecho() {
  if [ -z "$1" ]; then
      echo "if"
  else
      echo "else"
  fi
}

callmyecho() {
  append="stuff"
  myechoResult=`myecho`
  echo $myechoResult$append
}

# callmyecho
```

If you want to call `callmyecho` within the file and have it execute the `myecho` function within its block, simply uncomment `callmyecho` by removing '#'.

On the other hand, if you want to call on the `callmyecho` function from the terminal, then source the file script first as follows:

```
$ source ./file
```

Then you can call on any function inside that file script and it will execute.